# Android App - placing elements close to android nav (back button and co)

Tags: navigation, android, back-button, app

I want to place a element (which can be often used) on the bottom left corner of my app but i'm not sure if it's a good ui choice.
this app will run on IOS, desktop and android devices but it will be the same layout.

Can it be a problem regarding some devices where the nav button are also on the same place ?
On Nexus 5 its ok because everything in centered.

[image: buttons]

Comment: This is quite a frequent pattern used on many android applications, having action buttons placed at the bottom close to the navigation bar. As long as these are action buttons, and not in app navigation (on screen controls for this should instead be at the top right under the action bar), I see no guideline violation with this layout.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this quick answer.

I'm Thinking about a practice i've already seen on other apps. When you arrive on the app, you can see that the nav bar is sliding under the fold and become invisible (avoid the "Arggg I've touched the home button !") You have to slide it again in order to make it reappear.

But is this an android method or from the device himself ? To know if it's a good option for every devices.

Comment: Personally, I find buttons that are very close to any kind of device back buttons are bad design because it is too easy to miss tap and activate the wrong thing. I have done this many times and I am sure other people have as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## It's fine!

A quick glance through any major Android apps will show you that the menu or settings button alternates from top-left to top-right, and many other buttons go near the bottom. Aside from those standards, you can do almost anything.

As long as you provide ample finger-space for the buttons (good article at [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/02/21/finger-friendly-design-ideal-mobile-touchscreen-target-sizes/)), you can put buttons anywhere (sensibly) on an Android tablet.

It's important to remember that finger-space means adequately-sized buttons, as well as adequate spacing around them

P.S. The Sony Xperia is another tablet that shifts the Android navigation to the bottom left. It's annoying.